# Python - Converting a Google Sheet row to string

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

Right now I have a program that allows you to see rows one at a time. Although the problem is is that the `join` line doesn't work because the `results` variable is a list. Is there another way to do this?

```py
values = sheet.get_all_values()
current_index = 2
results = values[current_index:current_index+1]
results =  ', '.join(results)
A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8 ,A9 = results.split(", ")
current_index+=1
```

Comment: Could you give example of values variable, please?

Comment: What is `values`? The part '`join` line doesn't work because the `results` variable is a list' doesn't make sense because `join` should work on iterable objects.

Comment: I've updated the post.